# Finding the perfect number from 1 to n

Tags: java

I have a program to find the [perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number) from 1 to n:

[image]

How can this be reduced without changing it?

```
class PerfectNumber
{
    public static StringBuffer fact(int a)
    { 
        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer(" ");
        for(int i=1;i<a;i++)
        if(a%i==0)
        {
            sb.append(i+",");
        }
        return sb; 
    }
    public static String isPrime(int a)
    {
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=1;i<a;i++)
        {
            if(a%i==0)
        {
            sum+=i;
        }   

        }
        if (sum==a)
        {
            return "true";
        }
        else
            return "false";
    }
    public static int perfecrNo(int a)
    {
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=1;i<a;i++)
        {
            if(a%i==0)
        {
            sum+=i;
        }   

        }
        return sum;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.printf("%s%40s%15s%15s%n","NO","fact","sum","isPrime");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        for(int i=1;i<100;i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%n %d %40s\b %15d %15s",i,fact(i),perfecrNo(i),isPrime(i));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You have some good answers.  My only comment is that `isPrime` is clearly the wrong name for the method (as well as the column title in the output). It is not testing (printing) whether the number is prime, but testing (printing) whether the number is perfect.  E.g., you show 'true' against 6 whereas 'false' against 2 and 3.

Comment: Looks like Peter Taylor and Tamoghna Chowdhury covered my above comment in their answers.

Answer (score 10):

#### Indentation

To pick one example:

> ```
>         for(int i=1;i<a;i++)
>         {
>             if(a%i==0)
>         {
>             sum+=i;
>         }
> ```

What's going on here? My best guess would be that you're mixing tabs and spaces with a tabstop of 8. Be consistent: tabs or spaces. Changing the tabstop shouldn't break the formatting.

#### Names

> ```
>     public static StringBuffer fact(int a)
>     public static String isPrime(int a)
>     public static int perfecrNo(int a)
> ```

What do these three methods do?

- The first one produces a string containing the factors. Before reading the implementation I had guessed that it calculated the factorial. Name could be more descriptive: e.g. `formatFactors`.
- The second one tests whether the number is a perfect number or not. The name is simply wrong: it claims that the method does something different to what it does. It should be e.g. `isPerfectNumber`.
- The third one calculates the sum of the factors. The name certainly doesn't communicate that to me. It should be e.g. `sumOfFactors` (or `aliquotSum` if you don't mind the technical term).

#### Factoring out common code

All three of those methods have a loop which does the same thing: find the factors of `a`. That should be pulled out into a single method, which should have a suitable return type (e.g. `Collection<Integer>`, although there's a good case for `Set<Integer>`, or maybe some integer stream type, but I'm not up to date on Java 8).

Then two of the methods sum the factors: that's already pulled out into a method, so the other method shouldn't duplicate it. Instead you should have a very simple method

```
public static boolean isPerfectNumber(int a)
{
    return a == sumOfFactors(a);
}
```

#### Rethink method signatures

Why does `fact` return a `StringBuffer`? I can't think of many situations in which it makes sense to return a `StringBuffer` (or a `StringBuilder`). Either you're appending to a `StringBuffer`/`StringBuilder`, in which case it should almost always be an argument and doesn't need to be returned, or you aren't, in which case it makes more sense to return a `String`.

Why does `isPrime` (`isPerfectNumber`) return a string `"true"` or `"false"`? The `boolean` type exists for precisely the type of things which are `true` or `false`.

Comment: I added an addendum to your answer with the requisite Java 8-fu and some other things. Maybe you'd like to take a look?

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestion:

- **If you don't need thread-safety** you should replace `StringBuffer` with `StringBuilder`: it's the same API but StringBuffer is synchronized (read: slower)
- `sb.append(i+",");` is against the purpouse of a StringBuilder/Buffer, you should rewrite it as

  ```
  sb.append(i);
  sb.append(",");
  // or: sb.append(i).append(",");  
  // or: sb.append(i)
  //       .append(",");
  ```
- Booleans. Don't return true/false as String, `boolean` type exists! So

  ```
  if (sum==a)
  {
      return "true";
  }
  else
      return "false";
  ```

should be rewritten as `return sum == a;`

Comment: Better yet, just use `String`. The compiler will optimize it to a StringBuilder anyway.

Comment: @heijenoort I was going to suggest changing your code blocks into actual blocks instead of inline code (4 leading spaces on a line vs surrounding in backticks), but it appears that it doesn't work inside of a bulletted list?

Comment: @BrianJ You're right, I'm still new to codereview syntax. I just noticed that Peilonrayz already fixed my answer.

Answer (score 2):

*This answer is mostly an addendum to @[Peter Taylor's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/163381/100478), so I'll not address previously addressed points.*

First things first - you ask us to reduce your code without changing it. That, obviously, isn't possible. So you'll have to settle for changing your code. Others have suggested minor changes; however, I'll go wholesale with my recommendations. In fact, I'll even show you a way where your code becomes just 3 to 5 lines long! (Warning: Java 8-fu ahead!)

## Method names

Your method naming is plain horrible - it lies to the reader and API user (and that's after ignoring the typos - you probably meant `perfectNo` instead of `perfecrNo`.

As to why it lies to the reader of your code - that's usually you - and other users of your code - that has been already been clarified by Peter, so I won't bother with that here.

## Whitespace

Whitespace is free, and makes intractable sections of code more readable - here, space around operators and before opening braces is the Java convention.

## Bracing Style

Use a consistent bracing style for blocks - the Java convention is to put the opening brace on the same line as the declaration, and the closing brace on a new line at the end of the block.

Try to always use braces even for single-line statements - it lowers confusion originating from wrong indentation and makes it easier to add code later to that block.

## Method visibility

When you don't want a method to be exported (you don't, usually, for methods that are implementation details)(that is, to be available to anyone for use and abuse), you want to use the `private` visibility modifier instead of `public` or `package private` (the default if you don't specify a visibility modifier).

I'll cut you some slack on this as it does not look like this app will ever present an API, but recommended practices are recommended for a reason.

## Method Signatures

It's easier probably for your formatting purposes to return `String` or `StringBuilder` - but that's not what one would expect.

In the case of `fact`, it should return `List<Integer>` (for ease of use) or `int[]` (for performance reasons, not that that should ever be your primary concern).

`isPrime`, (which should be `isPerfect` (or `isPerfectNumber` to satisfy my tastes), by the way) should return `boolean`.

However, you've probably noticed by now that `perfecrNo` is already returning the sum of the factors (shouldn't it be named `sumOfFactors`?) - so why not just use that in `isPrime`, excuse me, `isPerfectNumber`?

```
public static boolean isPerfectNumber(final int number) {
    return sumOfFactors(number) == number;
}
```

Note a few things:

1. The `final` keyword before the method parameter - which I named `number`, because that makes more sense than `a`: it signifies to the method which called `isPerfect` that it will not change `number`. Note that this modifier will also prevent any reassignments to `number`, which is OK as you don't reassign it anyway.
2. The spacing, bracing and indentation illustrates my above points.

---

About `fact` - remember how I suggested it should return a list of the factors, instead of formatting them into a `StringBuffer`? In this case, since the factors of a number should be unique, I recommend returning a `Set`, whose elements are guaranteed to be unique, and specifically use a `TreeSet`, as `HashSet` does not store its elements in a defined order, while `Treeset` stores them (for our use case) according to their natural order.

I recommend using a `java.util.LinkedList` as an intermediate in this case, as the elements of this are only ever iterated in order and the number of factors of the number is not known before the factors are evaluated - thus it will provide performance characteristics better than a `java.util.ArrayList` on large or highly-composite numbers with where the number of factors is large enough to require reallocations of the underlying array.

*Note:* You'll need to use `List<Integer>` instead of `List<int>`, as primitive types are not objects and hence cannot be used with generic containers without boxing to its wrapper type first. However, with the advent of autoboxing before Java 7, the process is transparent and thanks to caching will not incur a large performance hit from object allocation for small numbers (less than 127).

Try this:

```
public static java.util.Set<Integer> listFactorsOf(final int number) {
    java.util.List<Integer> factorList = new java.util.LinkedList<>();
    // I prefer preincrement as that has lesser a connotation of side effects
    for(int i = 1; i < number; ++i) {
        if(number % i == 0) {
            // Note that this `add` appends to the list and always returns `true`, so we don't need to check the result
            // Autoboxing magic happened here!
            factorList.add(i);
         }
     }
     return new java.util.TreeSet<Integer>(factorList);
}
```

Now, `sumOfFactors` simply becomes:

```
public static int sumOfFactors(final int number) {
    int sumOfFactors = 0;
    // Note for-each loop - standard for iterating collections of elements and arrays since Java 5
    // Autoboxing magic happened here!
    for(int factor: listFactorsOf(number) {
        sumOfFactors += factor;
    }
    return sumOfFactors;
}
```

Now, you feel like you've probably lost all your beautiful formatting! Not to worry - `toString()` to the rescue! It'll get you a `String` containing the `String` representations of all the elements in the `List`, separated by commas and spaces with the whole thing enclosed in square brackets.

So now we get to `main`.

Why hard-code `100`? I'll show how you can get the maximum number up to which to check for perfect numbers as a command line argument, and improve usability while at it!

```
private static final int defaultMaxNumber = 100;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Note standard camelCase naming style for identifiers
    int maxNumber = defaultMaxNumber;
    if(args.length > 0) {
        String argument = args[0];
        // Error handling is good!
        try {
             maxNumber = Integer.parseInt(argument);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
             // Somewhat more-user friendly than an Exception
             System.err.println("Command-line argument 'Maximum limit of generator' = " + argument + " must be an integer");
             // Exit with error status 
             System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    if(maxNumber <= 0) {
        // This is more user-friendly than the handler above
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Maximum limit of generator must be a non-zero positive integer, it is: " + maxNumber);
    }
    System.out.println("Enumeration starts from 1, upper limit " + maxNumber + " is excluded");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.printf("%s%40s%15s%15s%n","Number","Factors","Sum of Factors","Is Perfect Number?");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    for(int number = 1; number < maxNumber; ++number) {
        System.out.printf("%n %d %40s\b %15d %15s",
                          number, listFactorsOf(number).toString(), sumOfFactors(number), isPerfectNumber(number) ? "Yes" : "No");
    }
}
```

Your format specifiers totally mess up the output formatting - don't worry, I'll (mostly) fix it in the full program below.

Now, you see that we are repeating similar calculations thrice for one number. What this suggests is that we pass around intermediate results ("cache" them) so the process becomes faster. For this, we can combine all my previous suggestions into a whole program as below:

```
import java.util.*;

public class PerfectNumbers { 

    private static final int DefaultMaxNumber = 100;
    
    public static boolean isPerfectNumber(final int number) {
        return isPerfectNumber(number, sumOfFactors(number));
    }

    // Implementation details - should be private
    
    private static boolean isPerfectNumber(final int number, final int sumOfFactorsOfNumber) {
        return sumOfFactorsOfNumber == number;
    }
    
    private static Set<Integer> listFactorsOf(final int number) {
        List<Integer> factorList = new LinkedList<>();
        for(int i = 1; i < number; ++i) {
            if(number % i == 0) {
                factorList.add(i);
            }
         }
         return new TreeSet<>(factorList);
    }
    
    private static int sumOfFactors(int number) {
        return sumOfFactors(listFactorsOf(number));
    }
    
    private static int sumOfFactors(Set<Integer> factorList) {
        int sumOfFactors = 0;
        for(int factor: factorList) {
            sumOfFactors += factor; 
        }
        return sumOfFactors;
    }
    
    // End implementation details
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int maxNumber = DefaultMaxNumber;
        if(args.length > 0) {
            String argument = args[0];
            try {
                 maxNumber = Integer.parseInt(argument);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                 System.err.println("Command-line argument 'Maximum limit of generator' = " + argument + " must be an integer");
                 System.exit(1);
            }
        }
        if(maxNumber <= 0) {
            
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Maximum limit of generator must be a non-zero positive integer, it is: " + maxNumber);
        }
        System.out.println("Enumeration starts from 1, upper limit " + maxNumber + " is excluded");
        // Output formatting - safe for maxNumber upto 120, for 96 chars per line
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.printf("%s%45s%20s%24s%n", "Number", "Factors", "Sum of Factors", "Is Perfect Number?");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        for(int number = 1; number < maxNumber; ++number) {
            Set<Integer> factorList = listFactorsOf(number);
            String factorListString = factorList.toString();
            int sumOfFactors = sumOfFactors(factorList);
            int numberOfDigits = String.valueOf(number).length();
            // Output formatting - safe for maxNumber upto 120, for 96 chars per line
            System.out.printf("%d%" + (50 - numberOfDigits - 1) + "s%15d%20s%n",
                              number, factorListString, sumOfFactors, isPerfectNumber(number, sumOfFactors) ? "Yes" : "No");
        }
    }    
}
```

Obligatory screenshot of output (don't mind me showing off my custom Rainmeter setup :P) - forgive the low font size, the whole thing wouldn't fit otherwise.

[image: Output Screenshot]

I did promise some Java 8-fu, so here you go!

I won't bother explaining this too much, it should be self-explanatory once the concept of higher-order functions and lambdas are understood, along with method references. Reading up a bit on Java 8 would help a lot more than me trying to explain this. I'll also sacrifice a bit of good design to keep it short - it'll all be in the `main` method.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.function.*;

public class PerfectNumbersJava8 { 

    private static final int DefaultMaxNumber = 100;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int maxNumber = DefaultMaxNumber;
        if(args.length > 0) {
            String argument = args[0];
            try {
                 maxNumber = Integer.parseInt(argument);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                 System.err.println("Command-line argument 'Maximum limit of generator' = " + argument + " must be an integer");
                 System.exit(1);
            }
        }
        if(maxNumber <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Maximum limit of generator must be a non-zero positive integer, it is: " + maxNumber);
        }
        System.out.println("Enumeration starts from 1, upper limit " + maxNumber + " is excluded");
        // Output formatting - safe for maxNumber upto 120, for 96 chars per line
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.printf("%s%45s%20s%24s%n", "Number", "Factors", "Sum of Factors","Is Perfect Number?");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        IntStream.range(1, maxNumber).forEach(number -> {
            Set<Integer> factorList = IntStream.range(1, number)
                                            .filter(i -> (number % i) == 0))
                                            // No autoboxing for streams :(
                                            .boxed()
                                            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
            String factorListString = factorList.toString();
            int sumOfFactors = factorList.stream()
                                         // And no auto-unboxing either :( :(
                                         .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                                         .sum();
            int numberOfDigits = String.valueOf(number)
                                       .length();
            // Output formatting - safe for maxNumber upto 120, for 96 chars per line
            System.out.printf("%d%" + (50 - numberOfDigits - 1) + "s%15d%20s%n",
                              number, factorListString, sumOfFactors, 
                              (number == sumOfFactors) ? "Yes" : "No");
        });
    }    
}
```

Output is the same as above.

Answer (score 0):

There is some redundancy in your code. In fact, `isPrime` and `perfecrNo` are doing the same calculations, they can be combined as follows:

```
 public static void combined(int a){
  int sum=0;
  StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer(" ");
  for(int i=1;i<a;i++){
    if(a%i==0){
       sum=sum+i;
       sb.append(i+",");
    }
  }
  boolean isperfect=a==sum;
  System.out.println("%n %d %40s\b %15d %15s",a,sb,sum,isperfect);

}
```

Comment: You probably want `System.out.printf`, not `System.out.println`. `println` does not support varargs format arguments.